# Finding an angle in a triangle?

Tags: trigonometry

Given the following picture, how do I find $\angle CDA$?

[image]

**Attempt**:

I have found the following angles, which I think may be useful:
$$
\angle BAC = \arctan(3),\quad
\angle ABC = \arctan(2),\quad
\angle BCA = \arctan(1).
$$
But I don't know how to go on.

Comment: Hey and Welcome to MSE! Could you please tell us where are you stuck? What have you tried so far?

Comment: So this is not the original problem? In this case you shouid post the whole question. Maybe there are some other information there we could use.

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa I understand what you're saying, but there is no additional information that I have not already provided.

Comment: But the how do you know these angles?

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa if you see the attached image, the triangle is drawn over a grid, giving me necessary side lengths.

Comment: Where exactly is point $D$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the points are at the exact grid points where it *looks* like they are, the line $AD$ is orthogonal to $BC$. The line $BC$ goes $2$ units down for each unit we go to the right, and if we turn that $90^\circ$, we get a line which goes $1$ unit up for every $2$ units to the right. That's what $AD$ does.

Comment: @RubyPa I'm not assuming that in any way. I'm _showing_ it. There may be details I've glossed over, but this approach is definitely viable.

Comment: Ahhh yes I see what you mean. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Haha that's one sweet question you could do with the converse of Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

Note that $\angle DAB = \arctan(\dfrac{1}{2})\\ $ (two units over four ones). Thus,

$$\angle ADC = 180°- (\angle DAB+ \angle CBA) = 180° - \arctan(\dfrac{1}{2})-\arctan(2) = 90°.$$